# When I try to connect to the local port of a proxy server, i get a bind error

Tags: java, netty

I created a proxy server using Netty.  The proxy server was modeled after the example. If my shutdown method correct?

I am using a servlet to receive requests, parse header information and send the request to the proxy server.  The first time I run my jMeter test is binds correctly.  The second time I run the jMeter tests I get this error:

```
The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it 
from fulfilling this              
request.org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException:
Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:2011
org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
```

Here is my run() method in the server and the shutdown method in the server:

```
public void run() {
logger.debug("starting the run() method in XxxxxxxxxServer");

// Configure the bootstrap
Executor executor   =   Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap =   
new ServerBootstrap( new     NioServerSocketChannelFactory(executor, executor));

// set up the message pipeline
ClientSocketChannelFactory clientFactory    =
new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(executor, executor);

serverBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new XxxxxxxxxPipelineFactory(clientFactory, VRSserver, remotePort));

String binding = "0.0.0.0";
// start the server, creating the new local port for the device
channel = serverBootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(binding ,localPort));
}


public void shutdown() {
logger.debug("starting the shutdown() method in AccugradeServer");

// unbind all channels created by the factory
if (serverBootstrap != null) {
    serverBootstrap.getFactory().releaseExternalResources();
    serverBootstrap.getFactory().shutdown();
}

// close all child channels accepted by the unbound channels
if (channel != null) {
    channel.unbind();
    channel.close().awaitUninterruptibly();
}

// releasing resources
if (serverBootstrap != null) {
    serverBootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
    serverBootstrap.shutdown();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you should bind to the local ip, which is :

```
String binding = "127.0.0.1";
```

and check that you don't have any running service on the port 2011 :

```
netstat -antp | grep 2011
```

should return no line

Comment: I tried the suggestion.  I am getting the same error.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to use this code without resorting to a command line check.  Is my shutdown method correct?

Comment: A message, doPost, is sent to a servlet.  The first time the servlet creates the proxy server and calls it xxXxx.run(); I get information back from the proxy.  There are no errors.  When I send a second message, second doPost, to the servlet, the servlet creates a new proxy server.  When execution gets to: channel = serverBootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(binding ,localPort)); I get the error that the port is already in use.  I have run the netstat command.  I do not see any process on the port.